# coordinator pattern is not pushing to the NextViewController

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, coordinator-layout

Here is the AppDelegate.swift implementation/ configuration:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
var coordinator: MainCoordinator?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    //        Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
    //        FirebaseApp.configure()
    let navigationController = UINavigationController()
    coordinator = MainCoordinator(navigationController: navigationController)
    coordinator?.start()
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

here is the MainCoordinator.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MainCoordinator: Coordinator {
    var subCoordinators = [Coordinator]()
    var navigationController: UINavigationController

    init(navigationController: UINavigationController) {
        self.navigationController = navigationController
    }
    func start() {
        let VC = SplashViewController.instantiate()
        VC.coordinator = self
        navigationController.pushViewController(VC, animated: false)
        NSLog("view Started")


    }

    func goToMerchandizeEntranceView() {

        let vc = MerchandizeEntranceViewController.instantiate()
        vc.coordinator = self
        navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

    func gotoMerchandizeRequestView() {

        let vc = MerchandizeRequestStatusViewController.instantiate()
        vc.coordinator = self
        navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }


}
```

Here inside MainVC, in didselectItemAt IndexPath method of collection View should trigger to the next VC, however, VC is not triggered and displayed on secreen, " NsLog" prints the message though..  Can Anyone help me explain where i am wrong..?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if collectionView == menuCollectionView {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            coordinator?.goToMerchandizeEntranceView()
            NSLog("Receiving touch")
        case 1:
            coordinator?.gotoMerchandizeRequestView()
             NSLog("Receiving touch")
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    else {

        NSLog("define action for story cell")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: Since you're using storyboard you should instantiate view controller from storyboard like this:

```
func goToMerchandizeEntranceView() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    if let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MerchandizeEntranceViewController") as? MerchandizeEntranceViewController {
        vc.coordinator = self
        navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    } else {
        print("Could not instantiateViewController: MerchandizeEntranceViewController")
    }
}

func gotoMerchandizeRequestView() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    if let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MerchandizeRequestStatusViewController") as? MerchandizeRequestStatusViewController {
        vc.coordinator = self
        navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    } else {
        print("Could not instantiateViewController: MerchandizeEntranceViewController")
    }
}
```

Seems your coordinator is not initialized in `MainVC`. You should initialize your coordinator in `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let navigationController = navigationController {
        coordinator = MainCoordinator(navigationController: navigationController)
    }
}
```

Comment: I applied it but still blank screen (

Comment: What do you mean a blank screen? Is navigation working properly? Is the view controller you're navigating to properly initialized?

Comment: I actually have already rootviewscontroller in app delegate, and controllers are triggered through storyBoard using extension, However I wanted to use this coordinator pattern inside UICollectionView didselect method to navigate through the views which collection cells hold, is it actually possible? actually it doesn not have to interfere with the other views for the time being at least )

Comment: You seem to be using instantiate() method. If you're using storyboard you should instantiate view controllers via storyboard.

Comment: yeah exactly, right.. i was using using storyBoard instantiate(with identifier: string). method, but as i could not implemented the collectionView didselectItemAtIndex method with storyBoard, I found it useful actually to use the coordinator pattern

Comment: oh btw, is there any way to apply this coordinator pattern only to a specific viewcontroller or  relationship between specific controllers, lets say, only mainVC and LogInVc uses the coordinator pattern, and other VCs use the storyBoard..?

Comment: Yes, you can use it only where ever you like. Maybe you should try to implement it without a coordinator and then convert it to this pattern to minimise errors and for more understandability.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, besides the view controllers instantiation mentioned above, another point that might be a source of issues is that `coordinator.start` is being called before the navigation controller is added to the window. I would modify the AppDelegate to be something like this:

```
let navigationController = UINavigationController()
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

coordinator = MainCoordinator(navigationController: navigationController)
coordinator?.start()
```